# How to remove all transactions in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In a test environment I need to erase all the transactions in a hyperledger network. I could delete all the peers and then create new ones but this is a lot of work. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are expected to be permanent. That's the beauty of blockchain.

The more you can do is switch off all your orderers/peers, delete the volumes that persist the state (those mapped to /var/hyperledger/production or to /opt/couchdb/data in the case of CouchDB) and switch on the orderers/peers again.